# making changes to a file i didn't create and now the button wont function

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button

im a simple User interface designer with a bit of knowledge in Flash.  I was asked to resize another person's flash file.  So i opened the file in ANimate CC.  I changed the file dimensions but didn't change the actions of the button.  So after i exported it the button function no longer worked.  Not sure why since it worked before and now it doesn't.  Any ideas how to get the button to work.  i need it to go to the url google.org

here is the AS3

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

// =========================== CLICKTAG STUFF        ==================================
//    ========================================================================= ====
ct.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleClick);
ct.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER,handleMouseOver);
ct.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT,handleMouseOut);

function handleClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
  ExternalInterface.call("ctaClick");
  trace("clicktag clicked...");
  /*var flashVars:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;
  if (flashVars.clickTag) {
  navigateToURL(new URLRequest(flashVars.clickTag),"_blank");
}
  trace("clicked");*/
}

function handleMouseOver(e:MouseEvent):void {
  cta.cta.gotoAndPlay("OVER");
  cta.gotoAndPlay("over");
}

function handleMouseOut(e:MouseEvent):void {
  cta.gotoAndPlay("out");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code that's called when the button is clicked is external in JavaScript:

`ExternalInterface.call("ctaClick");`

Make sure you test the newly created flash file embedded in the HTML file it is supposed to be embedded in. The flash file is used like an image, it doesn't do much on its own except for some visuals on mouse over.

The functionality is in JavaScript. Without embedding the flash file, the JavaScript is missing and it doesn't do much.